# Grails gsp g:formatNumber formats negative currency strangely

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm using the [`g:formatNumber`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html) tag in my gsp to format currency, like so

```
<g:formatNumber number="${value}" type="currency" currencyCode="USD" />
```

Which works great for positive numbers, but for some reason negatives are formated as `($0.45)` instead of `-$0.45`.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's standard currecy format for English locale. You can change formatter locale (don't think that it's what you want), or use custom format, like:

```
<g:formatNumber number="${value}" format="$#.##" />
```

See docs for decimal format: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: ($0.45) is standard? Didn't realize that.